# DevExtreme - Erro Injecting the Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good afternoon,

I've got some difficulties in a tutorial that I am developing, the aim is to develop a SAP - Single aplication page in Angle, using the DevExtreme framework.

When insert the 'dx'

```
var = scotchApp angular.module ('scotchApp' ['ngRoute', 'dx']);
```

this error happens

```
$ injector: modulerr. Module Error
```

Without the 'dx' works fine

```
var scotchApp = angular.module ('scotchApp' ['ngRoute']);
```

Below I leave my code:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="scotchApp">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.4/js/dx.webappjs.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.4/css/dx.common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.4/css/dx.light.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

```
<!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">TimeSheets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Approval</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Vacations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
<div id="main">

    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

Js

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute','dx']);
scotchApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
    })

    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/contact.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
    });
})

scotchApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
$scope.mensagem = 'Buenos dias';
});
scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
$scope.mensagem = 'Hello';
});
scotchApp.controller('contactController', function ($scope) {
$scope.mensagem = 'Teste';
$scope.buttonText = 'O Bonito';
$scope.buttonClick = function () { alert('click click'); };
});
```

Someone can help me to know why I can not inject devextreme widget in my page? thank you and happy holidays

Answer (score 0):

include reefernce for ngRoute in your head tag after angular.min.js `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>`
and dx not a module, inject ngSanitize in your module

Comment: Ruben, first of all , thanks for the help. its working now, thanks